# Using a jQuery loop to determine if the value of a variable has changed at any given time

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write some jQuery that defines a variable called `progressTracker` which is the contents of a `div` id called indicator. Indicator at anytime, can change and contents of this div will be either 1 or 2. If the number is 1, then I am attempting to add a class of "working" (which has a background image of a loading.gif), if the value of #indicator changes to two, I need to add a class that will basically display a checkmark (have not gotten as far as coding this in yet). This works, but it crashes my browser lol. Please excuse any ignorance on my behalf while attempting to describe my issue.

```
var progressTracker = $("#indicator").text();
var doOnlyOnce = $(0);

while (progressTracker==1) {

    if (doOnlyOnce==0){                   
        $('.statusIndicator').fadeIn('fast').addClass('working');
        var doOnlyOnce = $(1);  
    }

}
```

Comment: It works? I'm surprised as you only get the `text()` of that `div` once. So it will never check it again. And why are you defining `doOnlyOnce` twice?

Comment: Because I tested the script with an alert in place, and it kept setting off the alert, so I thought that's what it was doing with the fadeIn line, running it over and over again, so that was my attempt to only make the script execute that code one time instead of over and over again. I actually should have removed that bit, I thought that may be causing the browser to crash.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying there, yeah I only define progressChecker once.. Hmm great point, so I need to define that inside of the loop, to keep it constantly checking over and over again?

Comment: What is the mechanism for changing the value? Are you doing it in your code? If you are programmatically setting the value, you could also append or remove a class at the same time to get your check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a recursive `setTimeout` to poll for updates:

```
(function progressTrackerPoll() {
    var progressTracker = $("#indicator").text();
    if(progressTracker === '1')
        $('.statusIndicator').fadeIn('fast').addClass('working');
    else
        $('.statusIndicator').removeClass('working').addClass('check_mark');
    setTimeout(progressTrackerPoll,200);
})();
```

It will poll every 200 milliseconds for updates. It's also contained in an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), so it shouldn't interfere with any of your other code. It's better than `setInterval` because if there's an error it doesn't continue endlessly and is overall less intensive on your browser's resources.

Make sure to avoid `while` loops for polling because they can cause blocking, which can completely lock up the browser, if the condition never evaluates to `false`.

Comment: This works great!! I don't know what to do if two people have posted answers that work.. I am humbled by the knowledge you guys have on this site.. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it way too complicated, not saying that it is really not working well with JS.

Consider this.

```
  // define new custom event
  $(document).on('isWorking.my', function(e, flag) {

     if (flag) 
          $('.statusIndicator').stop().fadeIn('fast').addClass('working')
     else
          $('.statusIndicator').stop().fadeOut('fast').removeClass('working')
  })

  // now in every place you want to update if you are working or not
  // instead of 
  $('#indicator').text(1)

  // you are doing this to start working
  $(document).trigger('isWorking.my', [1])
  // or this to stop
  $(document).trigger('isWorking.my', [0])
```

NOTE  jquery events allow you to pass extra params to event handlers, syntax is the following:

```
  // triggering event and passing params
  $(obj).trigger('someEvent', [param1, param2, param3...])

  // handling event

  $(obj).on('someEvent', function( e, param1, param2, param3) {
      ....
  })
```

You can improve this idea having multiple flags of etc but if you are really have trouble waiting for async operations to finish, such as ajax request, your true way is to use promises:

```
  // two ajax operations
  function loadCategories() {
      return $.getJSON('/category')
  }

  function loadProducts() {
      return $.getJSON('/product')
  }

  // something that should happen when both of them finished
  function renderMyUI(categories, products)

  // and kick off
  $.when(loadCategories(), loadProducts()).done(renderMyUI)

  // or a click event should kick it off

  $('button.load').on('click', function() {
       $.when(loadCategories(), loadProducts()).done(renderMyUI)
  })
```

Comment: Why is your flag an array?  I believe `[0]` is truthy, so `if(flag)` is always true?

Comment: Thank you so much!! The speed at which you guys answer these questions make me question why I am coding.. Been hung up on this for hours. I appreciate your help, your solution worked as well as Alex W's.. Thank you for lending me some of your brains..